# Group Video call in kurento android

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, kurento, livechat

I got the kurento sample video app from github. It is good for peer to peer for calling.I tried to make group video call in kurento. I can't get the proper code. I need the proper code to make group video call.

Comment: can you provide us with the working sample that you got

Comment: Please use the following link.. Thanks in advance ....https://github.com/nubomedia-vtt/nubo-test

Answer (score 0):

Sample already has the capability to make a group call, but example shows only one view at a time, you only have to manage how to make them all visible.

Comment: I am able to implement one-to-many. But want to implement many-to-many(video call). Can you guide me with it. thanks..